# mono: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, apt

I followed [these instructions](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/) (for ubuntu 20.04) ending in `sudo apt install mono-complete`. Everything looks fine during download/install, but afterwards my console looks roughly like this:

```
$ mono
command not found: mono
$ which mono
mono not found
```

`find / -name mono` finds some directories, but no executables.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Pop
Description:    Pop!_OS 21.04
Release:    21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

I've been searching SO and google for an hour now with no luck. Where's my mono???

Comment: `mono-complete` https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/mono-complete has `mono-runtime` as one of the many dependencies.  'mono-runtime' provides `/usr/bin/mono` https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/mono-runtime/filelist

Comment: @KnudLarsen `sudo apt install mono-runtime` says `mono-runtime is already the newest version`... :(

Comment: `/usr/bin/mono` is a symlink to `/usr/bin/mono-sgen` from the package `mono-sgen` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=+mono-sgen&searchon=contents ............. I guess you will have to investigate what you got installed : You already have the mono-runtime link with all dependencies.